# TypeError: deprecate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'

Tags: python, huggingface, stable-diffusion

Error details:

```
Fetching 16 files: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 16/16 [00:00<00:00, 66117.11it/s]
  0%|                                                                                                                                          | 0/50 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (mo`your text`st recent call last):
  File "/data1/wz/research/pix2pix-zero/src/inversion.py", line 58, in <module>
    x_inv, x_inv_image, x_dec_img = pipe(
                                    ^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/research/pix2pix-zero/src/utils/ddim_inv.py", line 106, in __call__
    noise_pred = self.unet(latent_model_input,t,encoder_hidden_states=prompt_embeds,cross_attention_kwargs=cross_attention_kwargs,).sample
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/diffusers/models/unet_2d_condition.py", line 582, in forward
    sample, res_samples = downsample_block(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/diffusers/models/unet_2d_blocks.py", line 837, in forward
    hidden_states = attn(
                    ^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/diffusers/models/transformer_2d.py", line 265, in forward
    hidden_states = block(
                    ^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/diffusers/models/attention.py", line 291, in forward
    attn_output = self.attn1(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/diffusers/models/cross_attention.py", line 205, in forward
    return self.processor(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/research/pix2pix-zero/src/utils/cross_attention.py", line 7, in __call__
    attention_mask = attn.prepare_attention_mask(attention_mask, sequence_length)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix-zero/lib/python3.11/site-packages/diffusers/models/cross_attention.py", line 260, in prepare_attention_mask
    deprecate(
TypeError: deprecate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'
```

This is the function in `cross_attention`

```py
 def prepare_attention_mask(self, attention_mask, target_length, batch_size=None):
        if batch_size is None:
            deprecate(
                "batch_size=None",
                "0.0.15",
                message=(
                    "Not passing the `batch_size` parameter to `prepare_attention_mask` can lead to incorrect"
                    " attention mask preparation and is deprecated behavior. Please make sure to pass `batch_size` to"
                    " `prepare_attention_mask` when preparing the attention_mask."
                ),
            )
            batch_size = 1

        head_size = self.heads
        if attention_mask is None:
            return attention_mask

        if attention_mask.shape[-1] != target_length:
            if attention_mask.device.type == "mps":
                # HACK: MPS: Does not support padding by greater than dimension of input tensor.
                # Instead, we can manually construct the padding tensor.
                padding_shape = (attention_mask.shape[0], attention_mask.shape[1], target_length)
                padding = torch.zeros(padding_shape, dtype=attention_mask.dtype, device=attention_mask.device)
                attention_mask = torch.cat([attention_mask, padding], dim=2)
            else:
                attention_mask = F.pad(attention_mask, (0, target_length), value=0.0)

        if attention_mask.shape[0] < batch_size * head_size:
            attention_mask = attention_mask.repeat_interleave(head_size, dim=0)
        return attention_mask
```

My python version is 3.11, is that version incorrect or should something else be done to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading diffusers version to 0.12.0 works for me.

Comment: You can leave a comment on such an answer, not in the actual thread!